# Warum geht der "Esel" voran?

Tags: etymology

In einer anderen [Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/20439/1224) hier, kam die Redensart "Der Esel geht voran" zum Thema. Es gibt eine handvoll Variationen dazu ("Ich und Esel", "Der Esel nennt sich selbst zuerst"); nur frage ich mich:
Warum der Esel?

Im [Redensart-Index](http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=ein%20Esel&bool=relevanz&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou) habe ich folgenden Hinweis gefunden:

> Der Esel macht "Ih Ah", was als Abkürzung für "Ich und dann die anderen" interpretiert werden kann.

Ich kann mir nicht vorstellen, dass das der Ursprung ist. Ich denke eher, das ist irgendjemandem mal viele Jahre später aufgefallen und hat das ganze rückwärts aufgezogen.

Ein Esel wird als "stur" angesehen, aber sich selbst zuerst zu nennen, hat nichts mit Sturheit zu tun.

Nun wird ein dummer Mensch auch schon mal als *Esel* bezeichnet, aber auch hier: sich selbst voranstellen hat nichts mit Dummheit zu tun. (Wobei ich fast befürchte, dass doch hier der Hund begraben liegt...)

Dazu übrigens im Grimmschen Wörterbuch:

> da aber sämtliche thiere dem menschen gegenüber für unvernünftig und dumm gelten, so wird mit thier und vieh selbst, besonders mit rind, ochs, schaf und esel geschmäht und gescholten; der esel heiszt nicht nur arm und gering, sondern auch dumm, faul, träge, plump, grob, frech und geil (ἀσελγής), weil diese eigenschaften an seiner natur hervortreten, er steht im gegensatz zu dem ihm sonst ähnlichen edeln und raschen rosse und wird verachtet, ὄνου ὑβριστότερος, ἀσελγέστερος lautet die schelte auf einen menschen, der ihm gleicht; quid nunc te, asine, literas doceam? non opus est verbis sed fustibus. Cic. Pis. 30;

So richtig lässt sich daraus nicht nachvollziehen, warum man bei besagter Wendung zum Esel gegriffen hat.

Weiter heißt es dann zwar

> eine menge althergebrachter redensarten geht auf fabeln und bräuche und ist oft von höhnischer gebärde begleitet.

und es werden viele (mir größtenteils unbekannt) Redensarten aufgezählt, aber nirgends auch nur irgendetwas, was mir eine Idee bezüglich dieser Frage gibt.

Auch wurde der Esel häufig in der Bibel verwendet, aber auch hier scheint es nichts zu geben, was Sinn ergibt.

Leider habe ich auch schon nicht rausgefunden, wie alt die Redewendung überhaupt ist, und ob folglich Bibel und Fabeln überhaupt als Herkunft in Frage kommen.

Das einzige, wo der Esel tatsächlich voran geht, ist der Karren, den er zieht. Wenn ich mir jetzt eine Story ausdenken müsste, würde ich sagen, dass man damals zuerst seinen "vorangeheneden" Esel und dann sich vorstellte.
Was natürlich Unfug ist.

Hat irgendwer eine sinnvolle Herleitung?

---

Loong hat in einem Kommentar einen guten Punkt erwähnt. Im Duden wird eine Unterscheidung zwischen "Esel nennt sich [selbst] zuerst" und "der Esel geht voran" getroffen, und auch der oben verlinkte Redensarten-Index unterscheidet diese beiden Wendungen.
In der verlinkten Frage wird in einem Kommentar aber 'angedeutet' (sofern ich es nicht missverstanden habe), dass es mit der gleichen Bedeutung verstanden/verwendet werden kann.

Vielleicht kann auch jemand in seiner Antwort auf die Unterscheidung oder Überlappung der beiden Wendungen eingehen. Für beides gilt auf jeden Fall: Was zum Geier sucht der Esel da?

Comment: Im Duden Band 11 werden diesbezüglich (ohne Herkunftsangabe) zwei Redewendungen unterschieden: _der Esel geht voran_ (jemand lässt einem anderen nicht den gebührenden Vortritt) und _der Esel nennt sich [selbst] zuerst_ (jemand nennt bei einer Aufzählung nicht, wie es als höflich gilt, die oder den anderen zuerst)

Comment: Dummheit und Sturheit sind oft verwechselbar. Wenn man die Dummheit als Grundeigenschafft von einem Esel annimmt, dann scheint es mir kein grosser Schritt zu sein, auf Sitten und Höflichkeit zu schliessen. Wenn man zu einem grob war, wird er oft "dumm" genannt, oder?

Comment: @TimSeguine Ja, durchaus möglich. Ich räume ein, dass der Schritt von dem einen nicht gerade abwegig ist; doch bin ich mir nicht sicher, ob das der Wahrheit entspricht. Fraglich ist aber auch, inwiefern dieser Schritt von Dummheit zu Sturheit möglich war zu der (mir immer noch unbekannten) Zeit, als die Wendungen ihren Weg in den aktiven Sprachgebrauch machten.

Comment: "Nun wird ein dummer Mensch auch schon mal als Esel bezeichnet, aber auch hier: sich selbst voranstellen hat nichts mit Dummheit zu tun." - sich selbst nicht voranzustellen ist eine Konvention, die gelernt wird. Wer sich trotzdem selbst voranstellt, dem fehlt offenbar das betreffende (und womöglich noch mehr) Wissen. Kann die Assoziation mit Dummheit da noch deutlicher sein?

Answer (score 4):

Im Grunde kann man das nicht 100 %ig beantworten. Klar ist, dass gerne Tiere stellvertretend für eine bestimmte Charaktereigenschaft stehen.
Z.B.:

> Dumm wie ein Esel
>   Stur wie ein Bock
>   Schlau wie ein Fuchs
>   Langsam wie eine Schnecke

usw.

Diese Vergleiche treten dann in diversen Redewendungen auf, wie *Schneckentempo* oder eben die oben genannten *Der Esel geht voran* und *Der Esel nennt sich immer zuerst*.
Alles in allem ist die „Dummheit“ dabei aber nicht entscheidend, sondern mehr die Abwertung des Anderen, um ihm klar zu machen, dass er nicht so handeln sollte, wie er gehandelt hat.

Answer (score 2):

Der Spruch "Ich und der Esel" soll besagen, dass man sich selbst in einer Aufzählung höchstens dann zuerst nennt, wenn man in Begleitung eines Esels ist, niemals in Begleitung eines anderen Menschen. Also nicht: "Ich und meine Frau fliegen morgen nach Mallorca". Aber: "Ich und mein Esel gehen nächste Woche den Jakobsweg."

Answer (score 0):

Klassischerweise *treibt* man Esel, indem man hinter ihnen hergeht und sie - so zumindest ist das Bild - mit Schlägen aufs Gesäß zum Weitergehen anspornt. (Tatsächlich sind Esel ziemlich geduldige und friedfertige Tiere, die vernünftig bemessene Lasten auch ohne viel Zureden bewegen. Bockig werden die nur, wenn man sie schlecht behandelt oder überanstrengt. Das Bild ist also nur ein Bild.) Es gibt deshalb nicht nur *der Esel geht voran* sondern auch *erst der Esel, dann der Treiber*.

Daß der Hüter hinten geht, wo er die Tiere sehen kann und nicht vorn, wo er sich ständig umdrehen müßte, gilt, nebenbei gesagt, für viele Arten von Nutztieren. Auch bei Schafen oder Kühen geht der Hirte (wenn er allein ist) eher hinter als vor der Herde. Daß man hier ausgerechnet den Esel erwähnt, hängt damit zusammen, daß man denjenigen, der sich selbst zuerst nennt, mit dem Vergleich beleidigen will.